# decision tree redundancy optimization

Tags: optimization, decision-problem

First question in the computer science section. I am currently working on a solution that optimizes decision tree redundancy.

the following is an example of optimization:

```
|  D1   |   D2   | Outcome |
| true  |  false |   Yes   |
| false |  false |   No    |
| true  |  true  |   Yes   |
| false |  true  |   No    |

when optimized gives: 

|  D1   |   D2   | Outcome |
| true  |   -    |   Yes   |
| false |   -    |   No    |
```

I need to program this optimization. My decision tree will be different from the one that is shown here. I will have a string outcome, that is in no way a function of the input, and my input will contain 5 different possible inputs. `boolean, string, int, double` and `datetime` data types will also be present. Data in the input fields will be expressed using [FEEL](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/reference/dmn11/feel/data-types/) format.

**What I want to know** is if there already is a known algorithm for optimizing decision tables like these, or should can I expect to work this out by myself. I don't want to reinvent the wheel here, since this is quite a challenging project. An answer from the stackexchange forum suggested that I post here. He suggested that I start with the [Quine–McCluskey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) algorithm. I looked into this, but it seems like that it's calibrated for boolen based decision tables.

Currently I am considering an approach like the flowing:

1. If there are no duplicate outcomes, stop process
2. Select rules with duplicate outcomes
3. See which decisions are redundant by grouping/merging them
4. etc

<s>I am to write the code in C#</s>

EDIT:
Most inputs will be comparable to a degree. For instance, a string input will be one from a set of strings, and number values will fall in a certain range. But there is no guarantee they always will be.

Comment: Welcome to the Computer Science! Are strings comparable in any way? Are ints comparable? The implementation details are out of the scope here (so using C# is not relevant).

Comment: Thanks. Yes most input fields will be comparable to a degree. However not always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ID3 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm) is one standard way to construct a decision tree.  You can also look at successors like C4.5 and others.  These aren't guaranteed to give the smallest possible decision tree (that is known to be NP-hard) but the decision tree it outputs is often fairly reasonable.